# WordPress plugins recognition script in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to write a script that will uncover the plugins a certain WP blog employs... without success...

The final output file should include name and version of all plugins, activated and deactivated.

(Maybe grabbing all data from WP DB?)

Hope that makes sense.

Not sure it can be considered as question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already a couple of plugins that do this, search the plugin db e.g.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-list-plugins/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-plugins/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-showcase/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/i-make-plugins/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-list/
- etc... etc...

Furthermore there is a WordPress section on StackExchange...